# Why doesn't QList::at() check if index exists and also returns a read-only value?

Tags: c++, indexing, stl, constants, qlist

This question is more of an inquiry then actually seeking a solution for a problem.

`QList::at()` not only doesn't check if an index is out of bounds but it also returns a `const` hence it can be used only in a `read-only` scenario:

> **const T &QList::at(int i) const**
>
> Returns the item at index position i in the list. **i must be a valid
>   index position in the list** (i.e., 0 <= i < size()).
>
> This function is very fast (constant time).

I've just found out these peculiar implementation details of `QList` while trying to assign a new value to an element in my list and I'm wondering if there is a reason for doing that.

### **No check for index validity**

In `C++ STL` if we take `std::array` or `std::vector` (I'm not taking `std::list` since it doesn't have `std::list::at()` at all) we have the following:

> **std::vector::at**
>
> The function automatically checks whether n is within the bounds of valid elements in the vector, throwing an out_of_range exception if it is not

At first I thought that the check is not included to ensure the "This function is very fast (constant time)." however after looking at the implementation of `QList` I have to say even if the check was included a constant time (and high speed) is most certainly ensured.

A check for out of bounds would require two things (as far as I know):

- Check if given index is < 0 - this is a constant time check (`O(1)` if we use some wacky notation). Obviously we can't have negative index (we can in `Python` but it has another meaning ;))
- Check if given index is < `QList::size()` - constant time is also present here since the way `QList::size()` is implemented is:

  ```
  inline int size() const Q_DECL_NOTHROW { return d->end - d->begin; }
  ```

  This is again `O(1)` (if I'm not mistaken) since both values are stored inside the `QList::d` parameter which is a pointer to

  ```
  struct Data {
    QtPrivate::RefCount ref;
    int alloc, begin, end;
    void *array[1];
  };
  ```

  so accessing those and calculating their difference is not hurting the performance that much (obviously it has some minor impact since it introduces a couple of access and arithmetic operations plus backing up and restoring the stack due to the jump inside the `QList::size()` function).

So why dump the check for index validity? Is the performance impact actually that big?

### **Returning a read-only value**

By doing so the `QList::at()` function offers a hidden and (omho) not very useful feature which makes the difference in using it and `QList::[]` even more confusing. Also the `C++ STL` equivalent for `std::vector` and `std::array` allows assignment of new values using this function.

Comment: Returning a read-only value is a semantic choice on `at`. The no check for index validity is a conceptual choice: they assume developers know how to loop on a list with valid indexes (among other things, that's just an example). That's purely opinion-based

Comment: Qt classes are not suppose to through exceptions at all, it seems to me to be a reason for such a design of at method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are "3" ways of accessing an item from its index in a `QList`:

```
const T& QList::at(int) const
T& QList::operator[](int)
const T& QList::operator[](int) const
```

If you look at the doc, you will see that the last one is simply:

> Same as at(). This function runs in constant time.

So we are left with the first one (`at`) and the non-const `operator[]`. Here is the problem, the documentation of the second one tells you that<sup>1</sup>:

> If this function is called on a list that is currently being shared, it will trigger a copy of all elements. Otherwise, this function runs in constant time. If you do not want to modify the list you should use `QList::at()`.

**Note:** This is also true for `QVector`:

> Note that using non-const operators can cause `QVector` to do a deep copy.

<sup>1</sup> For `QList`, this is actually only true for [Qt 5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html#operator-5b-5d), not for [Qt 4](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlist.html#operator-5b-5d) (at least in the documentation), but for `QVector` it was already true for [Qt 4](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qvector.html#operator-5b-5d), so the `.at` method was probably made consistent between all Qt containers.

This means that you cannot use `operator[]` directly on a non-const shared `QList` or on a non-const `QVector`, you would need to do something like:

```
QList<T> &mySharedQList = ...;
const QList<T> &myConstRef = mySharedQList;
myConstRef[0]; // Only ways not to copy the original QList
```

My guess is that the purpose of the `.at` is to provide you with a method that **guarantees** a constant access time, whatever the `QList` or `QVector` is (which `operator[]` does not guarantee). You do not need such  method for standard library containers because non-const `operator[]` are already guaranteed to run in constant time (they are never going to make a copy).

Regarding the check on the index, this is probably to keep the behavior of the `operator[]` since, unlike `std::vector`, you probably want to use `.at` everywhere you only need to read data.

Comment: Well explained. Thanks. I also like the additional information on shared lists. Though I don't do that in my application I'm sure it will provide useful details for someone else.